# Check that getArguments has some data to be retrieved

Tags: android

```
Android Studio 0.8.7
```

I have the following function that sets some argument in the fragment:

```
 public static Fragment newInstance(UUID uuid) {
        Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: " + uuid);

        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

        arguments.putSerializable(EXTRA_JOB_ID, uuid);
        DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);

        return fragment;
    }
```

In my onCreate() I retrieve the arguments using getArguments like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* Get the arguments from the fragment */
    UUID uuid = (UUID)getArguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_JOB_ID);
    .
    .
}
```

However, sometimes there is a situation where I won't be sending any arguments to be retrieved, and my program will crash in that case.

Using Intents has the hasExtra method to check this:

```
 if(getActivity().getIntent().hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            /* There is something to be retrieved */
        }
```

I am wondering if there is something similar with getArguments

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: Probably you want to use `arguments.containsKey(EXTRA_JOB_ID)`? Also, I think you need to add manual `null-check` if the key is there but contains no data.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As an alternative suggestion to the other answers, your `newInstance(...)` method could be  designed slightly better. As it stands, it always adds arguments even if your `UUID` parameter is `null`.

Try changing it to this...

```
public static Fragment newInstance(UUID uuid) {
    Log.d(TAG, "newInstance: " + uuid);

    DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();

    // Don't include arguments unless uuid != null
    if (uuid != null) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putSerializable(EXTRA_JOB_ID, uuid);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Then in the `onCreate(...)` method of your `Fragment` check for arguments before anything else...

```
Bundle arguments = getArguments();
if (arguments != null && arguments.containsKey(EXTRA_JOB_ID))
    UUID uuid = (UUID)arguments().getSerializable(EXTRA_JOB_ID);
```

Answer (score 12):

[Fragment.getArguments](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) return an Bundle object all values send from other component. so you can use [Bundle.containsKey](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) for checking if key is available in received bundle or not:

```
  Bundle bundle=getArguments();

   if(bundle !=null)
      if(bundle.containsKey(EXTRA_JOB_ID)){

            // get value from bundle..
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of the `newInstance()` design pattern AFAIK is that you guarantee your fragment will have the arguments supplied to it when it's instantiated.

In other words, the reason you call `newInstance(something)` is because you know **something** will be passed into the fragments argument, so you can always retrieve **something** from the fragment's `getArguments()` method later on.

So if you do plan on passing null as an argument, e.g. `newInstance(null)`, which kind of defeats the purpose of using the newInstance design pattern, you're going to get a nullpointer exception.

You can call `getIntent.containsKey(EXTRA_JOB_ID)` to check whether your argument is null or not.