# Android IllegalAccessError to my class method

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I experience issue related to IllegalAccessError to my class method (only on Android 8 devices)

I updated:

- Android Studio to 3.3
- Android plugin for Gradle to 3.3.0
- Gradle to 4.10.1

**Here is my class:**

```
public class ShareDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(final @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable final ViewGroup container, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_share, container, false);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);
            readArguments();

            return rootView;
        }

        private void readArguments() {
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                sharedImageGridId = getArguments().getLong(Constants.Extra.SHARED_IMAGE_GRID_ID);
                isReadyToShare = getArguments().getBoolean(Constants.Extra.SHARED_IMAGE_IS_READY);
            } else {
       listener.onShareError(R.string.main_activity_share_photo_error);
            }
        }
}
```

**Here is crash stack trace:**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void com.jsdev.instasize.fragments.ShareDialogFragment.readArguments()' is inaccessible to class 'com.jsdev.instasize.fragments.ShareDialogFragment' (declaration of 'com.jsdev.instasize.fragments.ShareDialogFragment' appears in /data/app/com.jsdev.instasize-Bj_BEi7m9Z2r1b0gV7ktkQ==/base.apk)
       at com.jsdev.instasize.fragments.ShareDialogFragment.onCreateView(ShareDialogFragment.java:97)
       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
```

So readArguments() methods cannot be accessed in ShareDialogFragment class.

Googling didn't help find the answer.

Any suggestions? :)

Comment: Please have look this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497517/check-that-getarguments-has-some-data-to-be-retrieved)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your private method

```
private void readArguments() {
```

to public method as

```
public void readArguments() {
```

Comment: I think that is not the reason. Everything worked before updates of Android Studio and Gradle

Comment: Did you try clean and rebuild the project?